# How to distinguish between a system and normal process by getting processname and id in powershell using Java

Tags: java, powershell

Here is my code:

```java
public class PowerShellCommand  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PowerShellCommand call=new PowerShellCommand();
ids=(call.commandsilent("powershell.exe Get-Process | Format-Table ` Id"));
processes=(call.commandsilent("powershell.exe Get-Process | Format-Table ` ProcessName -AutoSize"));

}
String commandsilent(String command)throws Exception
   {String output="";
              //String command = "powershell.exe  your command";
 //Getting the version
//command = "powershell.exe Get-Process";
 // Executing the command
 Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 // Getting the results
 powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
 String line;
// System.out.println("Standard Output:");
 BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
   powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
 while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
output+=line+",";

 //System.out.println(line);
 }
 stdout.close();
 //System.out.println("Standard Error:");
 BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
   powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
   stderror="";
 while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
     stderror+=line;
// System.out.println(line);
 }
 stderr.close();
 //System.out.println("Done");
 return output;
   }
}
```

I have got the process ids in the string array processes[] and process id in string array ids[]

But *I can't find any method to differentiate between them*.

Comment: Is there a powershell command to distinguish between normal processes and system processes ? I am currently distinguishing as it gives an error on commandsilent("powershell.exe Stop-Process -ID "+id); , if it is an **System Process** otherwise it closes the process .

Comment: Further help would be highly appreciated

Comment: `Get-Process -IncludeUserName`?

Comment: That works but I only need Username with  using either id or processname of a particular process .

Comment: `Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Select-Object Id, Username`?
Or in separate arrays: `(Get-Process -IncludeUserName).Id` and `(Get-Process -IncludeUserName).Username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run method commandsilent("powershell.exe Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Select-Object Id, Username"); in main() method .